# Who do u get this errors while compiling discord bot

Tags: python

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    import sqlite3
    from config import settings

    client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents().all())
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents= 8)

    connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    @client.event
    async def onReady():
       cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            name TEXT,
            id INT,
            lvl INT,
            goals INT,
            assists INT,
            cleensheets INT
        )""")

        g = bot.get_guild(696354089851813978)
        members = await g.fetch_members(limit=3000, after=None).flatten()

        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guilds.member:
                 if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                     cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}' , {member.id} , 0 , 0 , 0)")
                 else:
                     pass

        connection.commit()
        print("Bot connected suffecently")          

    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}' , {member.id} , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0)")
            print("Bot connected suffecently")  
        else:
            pass

    @client.command(aliases = ['pass'])
    async def mypass(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if member is None:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                description = f"""User's pass **{ctx.author}** lvl is **{cursor.execute("SELECT lvl FROM users Where id = {}").format(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}**"""
            ))
        else:
             await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                 description = f"""User's pass **{member}** lvl is **{cursor.execute("SELECT lvl FROM users Where id = {}").format(member.id).fetchone()[0]}**"""
            ))

    client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

C:\Users\User\Desktop\CommunityBot>communitybot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\CommunityBot\communitybot.py", line 8, in 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents= 8)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 171, in **init**
super().**init**(intents=intents, **options)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1302, in **init**
super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 253, in **init**
self._connection: ConnectionState = self._get_state(intents=intents, **options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 284, in _get_state
return ConnectionState(dispatch=self.dispatch, handlers=self._handlers, hooks=self._hooks, http=self.http, **options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 221, in **init**
raise TypeError(f'intents parameter must be Intent not {type(intents)!r}')
TypeError: intents parameter must be Intent not <class 'int'>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are defining client twice right next to each other, but the intents section of the client definition doesn't accept an integer value, separate from permissions, which does. Here is the solution I came up with which is how I setup most of my bots:

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yep thanks, i fixed it a lot of time ago, anyways thank you